# Data Modelling for Fact Table which refers to a same column for Revenue, Standard Cost

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling, fact-table

the fact table in my current model have a column called reporting_currency.

and there is an other column called rep_id

If the rep_id is 1,2,3,4 then reporting_currency is for Revenue.

If rep_id is 5,6,7,8 then reporting_currency is Standard Cost.

What is the better approach to maintain the fact table when I want to create different columns for Revenue and standard cost.

The reason, I am asking is I want to calculate SGM % which is DIVIDE((Revenue-Standard Cost)/Revenue) as a column to establish the Static Segmentation process for percentage bucketing.

Comment: There's not enough information to understand the tradeoffs, or if your fact table design is simply not quite right.  IE why are Revenue and Standard Cost not separate columns on the fact table? What is the fact table grain?

Comment: Strongly suggest you create Measures instead of Calculated Columns.